# How to name a folder in next js such that it is skipped in the url path?

Tags: next.js

In my nextjs project, is it possible to ignore or skip a subfolder in the path of the url?

What I mean is, lets say I have a folder structure like this -

```
src
  - app
    - page1
       - page.tsx
    - page2
       - page.tsx
    - pagegroup (skip this in the url path)
       - insidepage1
          - page.tsx
       - insidepage2
          - page.tsx
       - insidepage3
          - page.tsx
```

i want insidepage to be accessed by url -

`/insidepage1`

`/insidepage2`

and not

`/pagegroup/insidepage1`

Is there a way to name a folder such that it becomes transparent? I did see it somewhere in a youtube tutorial but unfortunately can't remember or find that video now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.
If I name the folder in () it will become transparent.
So I can just name `pagegroup` to `(pagegroup)` and it won't be included in the url path.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups documentation for this answer